# Solr add and update pdf files

Tags: pdf, solr

I want to add and update pdf files to solrs index.
My scenario: I have a directory (mainDir), which should be indexed. This directory contains many subdirectories with pdf files. New pdf files and subdirectories can be created, updated or deleted.

I already created an Data Import Handler, which indexes all files in my directory recursive. Here's my config:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource"/>
  <document>  
    <entity name="file" 
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor" 
            dataSource="null" 
            fileName=".*pdf" 
            rootEntity="false" 
            baseDir="/mainDir" 
            recursive="true" >

            <field column="file" name="fileName"/>
            <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="fileAbsolutePath"/>
            <field column="fileDir" name="fileDir"/>            

        <entity name="pdf" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" url="${file.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">

            <field column="title" name="title"/>
            <field column="text" name="_text_"/>

        </entity>     
    </entity>   
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I ran the DIH, it worked, but I have no idea how to add/ update a single pdf file.
What is the best way to commit changes to the index. Later a node.js API should notice solr about changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### indexing one ducument

just call http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/dataimport?command=full-import

or use curl

curl http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -T "myfile.pdf" -X POST

refer to: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#using-curl-to-perform-updates

#### Prevent duplication

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/de-duplication.html#de-duplication

you can use somthing like this where you map the id is auto generated based on the content of the document witch prevent duplicated files on your index

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="dedupe">
        <processor class="solr.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory">
            <bool name="enabled">true</bool>
            <str name="signatureField">id</str>
            <bool name="overwriteDupes">true</bool>
            <str name="fields">text</str>
            <str name="signatureClass">solr.processor.Lookup3Signature</str>
        </processor>
        <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
        <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

and in requestHandler for name="/update/extract" and name="/dataimport" name="/update" add this

```
<str name="update.chain">dedupe</str>
```

and this will help also

```
<initParams path="/update/**">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="update.chain">dedupe</str>
        </lst>
</initParams>
```

#### last_index_time

you can put put `<field name="updated" type="date" default="NOW"/>` in your schema.xml

and if you want to use the value in your dataconfig use this var: `'${dataimporter.last_index_time}'`
the last index time is stored in data.import.properties

#### for node.js with solr

refer to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-node

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I do a full import with the clean option it will last 1 hour. So when I do it without the clean option, it will only commit changes? Because waiting 1 hour for a single change is too long.

Comment: I already tried the second option with curl, but my problem is that solr will index a lot more fields, which I don't need. When I do the indexing through my DIH I got less fields. I only need the path of the file and the content indexed. But the file path is not indexed with curl. The best option would be to inform solr about changes by posting only the path of the file and not the file itself, because API and solr server are not running on the same machine. So solr can check out the file informations and content through the path itself, like it's done by the DIH.

Comment: you can submit the path by your self with literal.fileAbsolutePath=path_to_the_file

Comment: I tried to add duplication prevention, but it says `unknown UpdateRequestProcessorChain: dedupe`. Do I need the schema.xml file because I am using the stanard  managed-schema file. Currently all requestHandler are defined in my solrconfig.xml.

Comment: managed-schema is  the replacement of the schema.xml in the new version of solr (it is the same), for `UpdateRequestProcessorChain` you need to field the first is `<str name="signatureField">id</str>` where to store the signature in this case the 'id' field you can change this to the default 'signatureField'  and add to your managed-schema if not exsist        `<field name="signatureField" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" />`, the second is ` <str name="fields">text</str>` change 'text' if not in you  managed-schema

Comment: Ok thanks, it's working for the DIH now.
But when I add the dedupe chain to `/update/extract` and I try to post a pdf with curl, I get an error: `unknown field 'pdf:PDFVersion'`.
I checked out the schema and the correct field is `pdf_PDFVersion`. When I remove dedupe from my requestHandler it's working and the pdf version is added to the field `pdf_PDFVersion`. Seems like generated fields from tikka are renamed when using the update chain dedupe.
I think it's only working for the DIH because I don't process much detected fields from tikka.

Comment: in ` requestHandler name="/update/extract" ` add ` <str name="captureAttr">true</str> <str name="fmap.pdf:PDFVersion">pdf_PDFVersion</str> <str name="update.chain">dedupe</str> ` **this will work**

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to use `<str> name="fmap.fieldName">new_fieldName</str>` for "renaming" on multiple fields.
I have another question. Is there a way to specify the fields which will be indexed. When I post my pdf file to `update/extract`, a lot of fields will be indexed, which I don't need. For example there are fields like `xmp_CreatorTool`. Is there a way to limit the fields or to ignore fields for the index?

Comment: **<str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>** and in the schema `<dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>` with `<fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />` this parameter causes all generated fields that aren’t defined in the schema to be map to ignored_* field withch is not indexed or store.